# Bus from Van/Turkey to Tabriz/Iran

Tags: buses, turkey, iran, tabriz

### Question

Looking for information on the bus from Van to Tabriz.

According to [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/Iran.htm), the Trans-Asia Express from Turkey to Iran has been cancelled and need to take a bus from Van/Turkey to Tabriz/Iran.

The page mentioned [ERDEM Turizm](https://www.facebook.com/ERDEM-Turizm-1073624912704617/) as a bus operator, and would like to know if this is the only operator or there are others. Also would like to know:

- Bus timetable (Seat 61 says 9/10/11 am)
- Prices
- Location of the departure
- Any means to book a ticket in advance

Any other information about Van, transportation to Tabriz, safety and annoyances, etc will be appreciated.

### References

- [Is Van a good base to visit Turkey and Kurdistan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3773)

Comment: Please note this is an unusually great question: well researched and not something trivially Google-able.

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Van/Tabriz-East-Azerbaijan-Province-Iran) is showing van to bus to train, with links to companies, online ticket purchase, and prices.

Answer (score 2):

Turkey's bus network is comprehensive, affordable, safe and comfortable.

From (dated) experience, I remember, however, that the further east you go, the harder it is to get reliable information on connections and time tables. Also, I can imagine that, with the current less-than-ideal situation in Turkey's southeast, scheduled busses, here, are less frequent than before.

Seat61's information on [how to get to Tabriz](http://seat61.com/Iran.htm) from *Tatvan* seems reasonable. Alternatively, you could also travel through Dogubeyazit, for example from Erzerum or Trabzon. However, when I made the connection at Dogubeyazit, there was no cross-border public transport. I had to get a local dolmus to the border and another one on the other side.

I tried [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Van/Tabriz-East-Azerbaijan-Province-Iran), but they give a public transport connection that travels through Azerbaijan's Nakchivan province. Though Azerbaijan has made it [much easier to get a visa](http://satprnews.com/2017/01/18/81-nationalities-now-exempted-from-long-visa-processes-to-azerbaijan/), I am not yet convinced these new tourist visas include Nakchivan (which is a stretch of land on the other side of Armenia).

Comment: I strongly recommend not to rely on Rome2rio for anything that actually matters.  Their information may be years out of date even in western countries with interconnected public transportation planners.